# ImageJ Rotation Macro Call Slows Down By Each Call

Tags: java, image-processing, macros, imagej

I have been working on a project in which I am trying to rotate images by ImageJ macros, basically the related part looks like:

```
IJ.run(sourceImage, "Arbitrarily...", "angle=" + angle + " grid=1 interpolate enlarge");
```

So when I make, lets say 5 calls with angles 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 to the method which runs the one above, the amount of time to execute this is growing bigger (both for threaded and single thread applications)
So approximately the processing durations are:

```
===========================
290 - 1. execution
656 - 2. execution
649 - 3. execution
1353 - 4. execution
6931 - 5. execution
===========================
```

so, why macro calls on ImageJ slows down when there are continuous calls to a specific macro?

Comment: Which ImageJ version are you using? The current version (1.47p) doesn't contain any command named `Arbitrarily...`. The *Rotate* submenu has been renamed to *Transform* in ImageJ 1.43h, 9 October 2009 (see http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/notes.html ), and I think the command you might want to use is now `IJ.run(imp, "Rotate... ", "angle=" + angle + " grid=1 interpolation=Bilinear enlarge");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're using the ImageJ macro language here. The code you show is Javascript or Java, and the command you're calling is running a Java plugin, not a macro.

With each call of `IJ.run(sourceImage, "Arbitrarily...", ...)`, you are **enlarging** your `sourceImage`, so with each following call you have to deal with more pixels.

Try leaving out the `enlarge` parameter from your function call and see if the slowdown remains.

If you want to start from the **original image** each time you are rotating, duplicate your `sourceImage` using `imp = new Duplicator().run(imp);` before rotating.

By the way, the command *"Arbitrarily..."* is still available for [compatibility reasons](https://github.com/fiji/imagej1/blob/master/ij/IJ.java#L287), but has been replaced a while ago by *"Rotate... "*, which you'd also get via the ImageJ menu when recording commands using *Plugins > Macros > Record...* and switching to *Record: Javascript* or *Java*.